# Karaf / Maven - class not found at runtime

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc, apache-karaf

I have built a bundle for Karaf with maven, and I included the `org.postgresql` dependency with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

I also included the jar of the latest version to Karaf's `lib/ext/` directory.
The bundle is loaded correctly. However, at runtime, when the bundle tries to load the driver with:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

I get the following error:

```
2015-05-28 14:36:07,218 | ERROR | qtp1270203840-47 | MyBundleServlet               | 124 - MyBundle - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | org.postgresql.Driver not found by MyBundle [124]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver not found by MyBundle [124]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_75]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)[:1.7.0_75]
...
```

Is there anything more I have to add?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a jar of dependency in an OSGi bundle using maven bundle plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605746/how-to-include-a-jar-of-dependency-in-an-osgi-bundle-using-maven-bundle-plugin)

Comment: It seems to me a different problem, because I need karaf to see a library inside its `lib/ext` folder..

Comment: Are you sure? Both that question and your question revolve around making a database driver accessible to a bundle... that's why I thought that would be a good place for you to look.

Comment: Yes thanks, anyway I tried and it does not work. Indeed, I do not want to embed my dependency in the bundle but to make karaf load it independently..

Comment: In that case you should start by declaring the dependency with `<scope>provided</scope>` in your POM. Other than that I am not familiar with Karaf and do not know what needs to be done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by embedding the dependency, using the corresponding tag (`<Embed-Dependency>`) in my `pom.xml`.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Import-Package>*;resolution:=optional,!org.postgresql</Import-Package>
                    <Embed-Dependency>postgresql</Embed-Dependency>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```